# gatsbys onClickOut is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I have got the following gatsbyjs component where i also use [react-onclickout component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-onclickout).

```
import React from "react"
import { useState } from "react"
const ClickOutHandler = require('react-onclickout');


const Searchdisplay = ({children})=>{

const [isToggledOn,hasInput,refresh] = useState(false)

onClickOut = (e) => {
  document.getElementsByClassName('ais-SearchBox-input')[0].value = '';
  this.setState(() => ({
    hasInput: false,
  }));
}
  
return(
   
   <ClickOutHandler onClickOut={this.onClickOut}>
      {children}
   </ClickOutHandler>

    )

}

export default Searchdisplay
```

Unfortunately i receive an error that *onClickOut is not defined*! Any idea that could help me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` will be `undefined` inside `Searchdisplay`.

Looking at your code, it seems that you are confused between functional and class based Components. Also, you are using `useState` incorrectly — though it will not throw an error, `refresh` will be set to `undefined`.

```js
const Searchdisplay = ({ children }) => {
  const [isToggledOn, hasInput] = useState(false) // refresh will be undefined, remove that

  const onClickOut = (e) => {
    document.getElementsByClassName("ais-SearchBox-input")[0].value = "";
    hasInput(false); // don't use this.setState here, that's for class component
  };

  return <ClickOutHandler onClickOut={onClickOut}>{children}</ClickOutHandler>;
};
```

*I suggest you to search the difference between functional and class components.*

Comment: It seems that i have got a problem with  hasInput(false) as hasInput is not a function.

Comment: `hasInput` would be a function. `useState` will return a value and a function to update that value. What error do you see in console?

Comment: I use the following code                                                                              
         <SearchBox
            class="ais-SearchBox-input"
            translations={{
              placeholder: 'Αναζήτηση συμμορφώσεων',
            }}
            onKeyUp={(event) => {

            setState(() => ({
            hasInput: event.currentTarget.value !== '',
            }));
          }}
          />         and when i use console.log(hasInput), it prints undefined

Comment: 1) use `className` instead of `class`; 2) Where did you get that `setState`? I think you want, `hasInput(event.currentTarget.value !== '')`

Comment: I get an error: search.js:61 Uncaught TypeError: hasInput is not a function
    at onKeyUp (search.js:61)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)

Comment: For class i use const onClickOut = (e) => {
  document.getElementsByClassName('ais-SearchBox-input')[0].value = '';
  setState(() => ({
    hasInput: false,
  }));
}  but there is no assignment (console.log(hasInput) undefined..... I could send you the whole code of this file

Comment: I just found the solution to my problem and now it works like a charm toggling hasInput between true and false. Regards